# css: four column width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-multicolumn-layout

I have a simple [page](https://jsfiddle.net/GHopper/0df7wnr2/)

What I want is to spread columns over the row. Is it possible to achieve this goal within this scheme?
I think it is quite useful to use `w-100` classes within single `row` to build multi-column grid. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have 4 columns per row, then add `col-3` class to your `div`.

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Block #1</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 item-card">
        Block #11
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 item-card">
        Block #12
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 item-card">
        Block #13
    </div>

    <div class="col-3 item-card">
        Block #14
    </div>

    <div class="w-100 divider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap grid system is using a twelve column system. Which means each row has total of 12 units. So to have 4 columns per row, 12 / 4 = 3

Read more from [Bootstrap Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

---

```
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

Comment: But what about `w-100` class which divides the content into rows too. Can I use it?

Comment: @GHopper yeah you can use it, remember to set the div height to at least 1px so that you'll able to see the divider, i've updated my answer with example